# Equivalent of `curl -v`, but as a server not a client?

Tags: http, curl

I know that `curl` is just for client side stuff, and I find it's `curl -v` tremendously useful for debugging HTTP issues.

However, I'm writing a client at the moment, and would love to see a verbose output of the data as it comes in on the server. What's the best way to do this? Is there a simple command line utility?

Things I want to see:

1. When the headers come in.
2. Does the connection stay open until the body is received?
3. When does the connection/message terminate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could give netcat (http://nc110.sourceforge.net) a try.

```
netcat -l 80
```

This way netcat starts listening on port 80 an you could use a browser to connect to that.

*This is my first answer so hope I'm doing this correct.*

Comment: You're wonderful! Have a good day! (I'll accept the answer as soon as the 5 minutes are up!)

Comment: Some versions of nc will require that to be `nc -l -p 80`